# Limits with Taylor series around zero

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, indeterminate-forms

I had some problems with the following two limits, which are supposed to be calculated with Taylor series:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^\sqrt{x}-e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{\sin{2x}}}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(1-\log{x})^{\sin{x^2}}}{(\arctan{x})^{3/2}}.
$$

Although the numerators are quite simple to develop in series, I stopped when I noticed that both denominators are not derivable in $x=0$, that is, we should not use Taylor series in $x=0$ to evaluate this functions around $0$. I wonder if is possible to consider right derivatives only, and study the behaviour of the denominators in a right neighborhood of $0$.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A good question (+1).

Answer (score 3):

**hint for the first**

We have
$$e^X=1+X(1+\epsilon(X))$$

then
$$e^{\sqrt{x}}=1+\sqrt{x}(1+\epsilon(x))$$
and
when $x\to 0^+$,
$$\sqrt{\sin(2x)}\sim \sqrt{2x}$$
thus your limit is

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2\sqrt{x}(1+\epsilon(x))}{\sqrt{2x}}=\sqrt{2}.$$

TOMORROW  I WILL LOSE POINTS .
NO ONE KNOWS THE REASON.

For this,  i leave.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. You can avoid the problem that $\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $0$ by considering just the  Taylor series of $e^t=1+t+o(t)$ and $\sin(t)=t+o(t)$ as $t\to 0$. Then, as $x\to 0^+$,
$$\frac{e^\sqrt{x}-e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{\sin{2x}}}=\frac{(1+ \sqrt{x}+o(\sqrt{x}))-(1- \sqrt{x}+o(\sqrt{x}))}{\sqrt{2x+o(x)}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}(2+o(1))}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2+o(1)}}.$$
Can you take it from here?
Use a similar approach also for the second one.

Comment: Don't you want big O notation?

Comment: Little-o notation suffices.

Comment: Oh, I see what you've done now, yes

Comment: Thank you @RobertZ, that is what I needed. For the second limit, I have just figured out that the numerator is $1+o(1)$, so it is not necessary to develop the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{e^{\sqrt x}-e^{-\sqrt x}}{\sqrt{\sin2x}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}{\sqrt x}+\dfrac{e^{-\sqrt x}-1}{-\sqrt x}}{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin2x}{2x}}}$$

Comment: Thank you! This is an elegant solution, but, if I am not mistaking, it does not make usage of Taylor series.