# Infinitesimal order with Taylor series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, infinitesimals

I'm here again with another exercise (after [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082255/limits-with-taylor-series-around-zero)) on Taylor series: determine the infinitesimal order for $x\to 0$ of the function
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^4+x^5}{x-\sin{x}}}\ .
$$
The problem is that, after having developed the denominator as $\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$, I have difficulties in determining the Taylor series of the whole function, as $f$ is not differentiable in $x=0$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you just want the infinitesimal order that is easy: the top is 4, the bottom is 3, so the inside is 1, which makes the square root give 1/2 at the end. If you actually want to expand in (rational, not integer) powers of $x$ then you should factor $\sqrt{x}$ out of the square root and then expand what's left.

Answer (score 1):

Using steps
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^{9}\right)$$
$$x-\sin(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^{9}\right)$$
$$\frac{x^4+x^5}{x-\sin{x}}=\frac{x^4+x^5}{\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^{11}\right)}=6 x+6 x^2+\frac{3 x^3}{10}+O\left(x^{4}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^4+x^5}{x-\sin{x}}}=\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} x^{3/2}+O\left(x^{5/2}\right)$$